# Javascript: getValueProperty of null?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, element

I am trying to write a single function to move an element, but I am encountering this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPropertyValue' of null**

```
    function Mover() {

    this.move = move;

    // Name of the moving element, property to change, endPoint - where to end the movement
    function move(element, property, endPoint) {

        var element = document.getElementById(element);

  // Get value of the desired property and turn it into number so that it can be incremented
        var propertyValue = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(property);

        var propertyValueInt = parseInt( propertyValue.substr(0,propertyValue.length-2) );

// This is where error starts: for some reason it says the aforementioned error
        var moveit = function() {

            propertyValueInt = propertyValueInt + 1;
            element.style.property = propertyValueInt + "px";

        };

        window.setInterval(moveit, 500);

    }

}
```

Where could the error be? I realize that it somehow rewrites the **element** property so that it is null, but why?

Thank you

Comment: From where are you passing these `element, property, endPoint` into `move` function ?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(property);`, since `element` can't be recognized as a HTML element. You've to fix the value of `element` to refer an *existing* HTMLElement. There's a typo/wrong text in the function call, or an element with the said `id` doesn't exist at the time this function is executed.

There's also an error in `moveit()`. When `property` is a variable name, this doesn't do what you expect:

```
element.style.property = ...
```

You need to use bracket notation:

```
element.style[property] = ...
```